# Streams - hasOutOfBandMetadata and getStreamingMetadata

Tags: sonos

We have some live streams we are implementing on our music service.

Playing the streams work fine, however for our reporting requirements we need to be able to send a track play event for each song that is heard during the stream. Plus, we'd like to be able to show the user what track is currently playing in the live stream.

The property streamMetadata.hasOutOfBandMetadata set to True for all metadata responses, however I never see our service receive a request for getStreamingMetadata.

The documentation only mentions getStreamingMetadata and hasOutOfBandMetadata once in the getMetadata page and I cannot find any more references to ensure I'm setting the properties correctly.

Here's an example of our SMAPI response for getMetadata on one of the streams:

```
<tns:mediaMetadata>
  <tns:streamMetadata>
    <tns:description>{{Show Description}}</tns:description>
    <tns:currentShowId>{{Show Id}}</tns:currentShowId>
    <tns:logo>{{Show Logo}}</tns:logo>
    <tns:hasOutOfBandMetadata>true</tns:hasOutOfBandMetadata>
    <tns:currentShow>{{Show Title}}</tns:currentShow>
    <tns:currentHost>{{Show Host}}</tns:currentHost>
  </tns:streamMetadata>
  <tns:itemType>stream</tns:itemType>
  <tns:mimeType>audio/mpegurl</tns:mimeType>
  <tns:id>{{Show Id}}</tns:id>
  <tns:title>{{Show Title}}</tns:title>
</tns:mediaMetadata>
```

The getStreamingMetadata is responding if I call it directly with an external SOAP client.

Am I approaching this problem the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

What type of audio stream are you attempting to play?  `hasOutOfBandMetadata` is currently only supported on HLS streams.

We do not currently support track level reporting for streams, but this is something that we are considering.