# Sonos player not calling GetStreamingMetadata

Tags: sonos

I have a live radio stream using HLS and I would like to display track / artist information when we're playing a song.

As far as I can understand from the API documentation and question [Streams - hasOutOfBandMetadata and getStreamingMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702263/streams-hasoutofbandmetadata-and-getstreamingmetadata) should be called for HLS if we have hasOutOfBandMetadata set to true.

The mime type we return is  "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl".

getMetaData returns a list of channels, where we build each channel with something like this

```
return new mediaMetadata
{
    id = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Prefix, (string)channel["id"]),
    title = (string)channel["title"],
    itemType = itemType.stream,
    mimeType = "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl",
    onDemand = false,
    liveNow = true,
    Item = new streamMetadata
    {
        currentShow = "Test title",
        currentHost =  "Someone"
    }
};
```

And getMediaMetadata returns

```
return new getMediaMetadataResponse
{
    getMediaMetadataResult = new getMediaMetadataResponseGetMediaMetadataResult
    {
        Items = new object[] {
            new streamMetadata
            {
                title = (string)mediaElement["title"],
                hasOutOfBandMetadata = true,
                currentShow =  "Test",
                currentShowId =  "MKDF24444",
                description = "this is the description",
                hasOutOfBandMetadataSpecified = true
            }
        },
        ItemsElementName = new[] { ItemsChoiceType.streamMetadata }
    }
};
```

With this configuration I cannot see any calls to getStreamingMetadata.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here may be that in your getMetdata response you should actually be returning the streamMetadata (not just in the getMediaMetadata response). For example...

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <getMetadataResult>
        <index>0</index>
        <count>3</count>
        <total>3</total>
        <mediaMetadata>
          <id>sta00001</id>
          <title>LIVE!!!! In NYC!!!!!!!!</title>
          <mimeType>audio/x-scpls</mimeType>
          <itemType>stream</itemType>
          <streamMetadata>
            <logo>http://example.com/sta00003.png</logo>
            <currentHost>Donna Summer</currentHost>
            <currentShow>Advanced D&D</currentShow>
          </streamMetadata>
        </mediaMetadata>        
        <mediaMetadata>
          <id>sta00002</id>
          <title>The Cheap Seats</title>
          <mimeType>audio/x-mpegurl </mimeType>
          <itemType>stream</itemType>
          <streamMetadata>
            <currentShow>The New Afternoon Show</currentShow>
          </streamMetadata>
        </mediaMetadata>
        <mediaMetadata>
          <id>sta00003</id>
          <title>Carol Burnett: The 'Fresh Air' Interview</title>
          <mimeType>audio/x-ms-wma</mimeType>
          <itemType>stream</itemType>
          <streamMetadata>
            <currentHost>Terry Gross</currentHost>
              <currentShow>Fresh Air</currentShow>
              <logo>http://example.com/sta00003.png</logo>
          </streamMetadata>
        </mediaMetadata>
      </getMetadataResult>
    </getMetadataResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```