# Getting metadata (track info, artist name etc.) for radio stream

Tags: sonos

I have already checked the following links but they weren't much helpful (in parenthesis I've explained why it didn't work in my case as suggested in their answers)

[Streams - hasOutOfBandMetadata and getStreamingMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702263/streams-hasoutofbandmetadata-and-getstreamingmetadata#) (our content is already HLS)

[Sonos player not calling GetStreamingMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505712/sonos-player-not-calling-getstreamingmetadata) (getMetdata is not called, only getMediaMetada is called since radio stream has unique id and is not a collection)

In Sonos API documentation it is mentioned that "hasOutOfBandMetadata" is deprecated and it is recommended that metadata be embedded inline with the content. However due to some limitations it can't be achieved in our service thus I have to go with the old way itself (whatsoever it is).

I suppose, ideally "getStreamingMetadata" should be called after setting "hasOutOfBandMetadata" to true but it's not happening.
Secondly, for testing purposes I set "secondsRemaining" and "secondsToNextShow" for different values to find out that "description" is also being displayed for those different time intervals (if I set secondsRemaining/secondsToNextShow to 20 then description is displayed for 20 seconds, if set to 200 then for 200 seconds and likewise). After the time lapses, information inside "description" disappears. So I guess there must be some call going to refresh metadata after the time lapses but couldn't figure out which call.
Kindly explain what is the proper way to get metadata for a continuous radio stream. On *TuneIn* radio you can find *Radio Paradise* for which metadata is getting updated as track changes. Even if they use metadata inline with their content there must be some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post the calls and the the response that you are sending? This would help with troubleshooting this issue. Also what mimeType are you trying to use?

At this time the only full supported method for getting metadata for a continuous radio stream on Sonos that will be guaranteed to work in future releases is to embed metadata in line.

Comment: Okay I am sending you the details on your sonos mail. Thanks